# Pn532 and Node MCU SPI

Tags: esp8266

I'm trying the Android Hce example in this PN532 library. The serial monitor gives me "Didn't find PN53x board". Can someone help me?

```cpp
#if 1
  #include <SPI.h>
  #include <PN532_SPI.h>
  #include "PN532.h"

  // SPI connections 
  //GPIO 12   MISO
  //GPIO 13    MOSI
  //GPIO 14    SCK
  //GPIO 15 SS

  PN532_SPI pn532spi(SPI, 15);
  PN532 nfc(pn532spi);
#elif 0
  #include <PN532_HSU.h>
  #include <PN532.h>

  PN532_HSU pn532hsu(Serial1);
  PN532 nfc(pn532hsu);
#else 
  #include <Wire.h>
  #include <PN532_I2C.h>
  #include <PN532.h>
#endif

void setup()
{    
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("-------Peer to Peer HCE--------");

  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
  }

        // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX);
```

Comment: Please share the full `void setup` as well as the `loop` and add your circuit. Did you check your connections if it doesn't find it?

Comment: @Juraj, So it is.  Thanks.

Comment: @PythonSchlange . I have shared the setup code above but it is not going in the loop part because when chip is not found it halts. I am mentioning here connections between esp8266 and pn532                                                                                                                     //GPIO 12      MISO
  //GPIO 13    MOSI
  //GPIO 14    SCK
  //GPIO 15    SS

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Are you sure all wires are perfectly connected? Did you measure the connection? I think it rather is a connection problem not a code problem, because you use the example. Please add an image of your setup to the question.

Comment: @PythonSchlange. Thank you for your help I was able to solve the problem by changing the SS line from GPIO 15 to GPIO 10. Thanks again for your help